# HTML bg color "flashing" on far smooth scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have:

- a list of anchors with `href=#id-*`
- a very long page with those ids ^
- `html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }`

and this happens:

[image]

I know what is the dark background flashing behind - it is the `background-color` of my `<html />` page element, and **I do not want to change it**.

Loosely, the document structure looks as follows:

```
<html style="background:#000">
  <body>
    <nav style="background:#000"/>
    <main style="background:#FFF"/>
    <footer style="background:#000"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I make it stop "flashing" the dark background?

**Note:** this happens on MacOS, both Firefox and Safari. Does not happen on Chrome.